# Friction forces on car wheel

Tags: forces, friction, interactions

I know that frictions means a lot for car wheel. I've been looking all around a lot and trying to figure all out.
I have found out about

- Coefficient of friction depends on slip ratio(which I am still not sure how to calculate)
- Friction determines maximum force exceeded to move car
- Friction depends from load on wheel
- Friction prevents car from sliding

However, I am not kinda sure how that all works - how to calculate each of the variables and forces(slip ratio, friction-determined maximum force for longitudal motion of car(both acceleration and braking) and friction resistance that prevents car from rolling away(makes it static when gas is not pressed) or sliding freely in curves(makes it actually possible to steer in curves).

What I want is to receive equations and explanations of how this all works, how each of forces/variables affect other acts of car, what should I take in etc. And, please, remember that this is for a simulation type of game(it shouldn't matter much, though).

Thanks!:D

Comment: BUMP comment, because I haven't got even any useful hints...:(

Comment: Comments don't bump anything.

Comment: I see. Propably must hope that someday someone finds this. I yet have 2 years of time to wait for the answer anyways. Well, as it's said - let's just wait... ;)